# Is there a way to perform multiple calculations in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to know is it possible to perform a series of calculations in stored procedures. I have used simple functions to perform calculations like monthly pay, net pay, and tax payable.

My requirement is that employee payslips for the given employees have to be generated. The base pay, taxable income, tax, and net pay needs to be calculated and stored for each payslip.

Below is my `Payslip` table in which data has to be extracted from to the procedure and some codes I've done.

I'm getting errors in executing in the procedure for the statement 
SELECT EmpPay(SELECT * FROM Payslip).

Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT
    BasePay, TaxableIncome,
    FORMAT (TotalHrsWorked*HourlyRate, 'C') as MonthlyPay,
    FORMAT (BasePay - TaxableIncome, 'C') as Net_Pay,
    FORMAT (TaxableIncome/BasePay, 'N3') as Percent_Tax
FROM
    Payslip


CREATE TABLE Payslip
(
    PayslipRefNo CHAR(6),
    [Date] DATE,
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE,
    TotalHrsWorked INT,
    HourlyRate DECIMAL(4,2),
    BasePay DECIMAL(6, 2),
    TaxableIncome DECIMAL(6,2) CHECK (TaxableIncome <= 9999.00),
    NetPay DECIMAL(6,2),

    CONSTRAINT pk_payslip PRIMARY KEY (PayslipRefNo),
);

CREATE PROCEDURE EmpPay
    (@TaxableIncome AS DECIMAL(6, 2), 
     @BasePay AS DECIMAL(6, 2), 
     @TotalHrsWorked AS INT, 
     @HourlyRate AS DECIMAL(4,2))
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (@TotalHrsWorked * @HourlyRate)
    RETURN (@BasePay - @TaxableIncome)
    RETURN (@TaxableIncome/@BasePay)
END

SELECT EmpPay(SELECT * FROM Payslip)
```

Comment: What errors? Where? Don't ask a question without actually explaining the issue

Comment: By convention [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is used to return an `int` status value, e.g. using [`execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments). As a best practice it should be left for a status value and `output` parameters and/or result sets should be used to return other data.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure can return data in 3 different ways:

1. Using `Return`
2. Using `Select` queries
3. Using `OUTPUT` arguments

**Return**

You need to note that if you use `RETURN` in your code, then codes after the `RETURN` will not executed any more. So you code will only return the first `RETURN`'s data. Here is how you can use `Return` and retrieve its value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRO_Test(@p1 INT, @p2 INT)
AS
BEGIN
   /*
     Your codes Here
   */
   RETURN 100
END
GO

DECLARE @returnResult VARCHAR(100)

EXEC @returnResult =  dbo.PRO_Test  @p1 = 10, @p2 = 20

SELECT @returnResult
```

**Select queries**

You can return multiple result sets from the stored procedure using `Select` queries. Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRO_Test(@p1 INT, @p2 INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @p1, @p1;
    SELECT @p2, @p1;
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.PRO_Test @p1 = 0, @p2 = 0;
```

**Output parameter**

You can also return multiple data using Output parameters, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRO_Test(@p1 INT, @p2 INT, @p3 VARCHAR(100) OUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @p3 = 'I am output'
END;
GO

DECLARE @p VARCHAR(100)
EXEC dbo.PRO_Test @p1 = 0, @p2 = 0, @p3 = @p OUT;
SELECT @p
```

You can use all the aforementioned ways, all together.

One important note about your query is, that you need to use `EXEC` or `EXECUTE` in order to execute a stored procedure, and you can not call a stored procedure using `SELECT`.

**Finally**

In your query in fact you can resolve the issue by write a `SELECT` query which returns 3 columns! You can rewrite your query as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmpPay
    (@TaxableIncome AS DECIMAL(6, 2), 
     @BasePay AS DECIMAL(6, 2), 
     @TotalHrsWorked AS INT, 
     @HourlyRate AS DECIMAL(4,2))
AS
BEGIN
    Select (@TotalHrsWorked * @HourlyRate) as Col1, (@BasePay - @TaxableIncome) as Col2,(@TaxableIncome/@BasePay) as Col3
END

EXEC EmpPay @TaxableIncome = <your value>, @BasePay = <your value>,...
```

In order to iterate inside your table and call the SP for each records inside the table you need to write a `CURSOR`, however if the SP is simply doing some calculations and `SELECT`s, then you can rewrite your SP, as User Defined Function, and use it inside your `SELECT`, without the need of `CURSOR` or SP.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination, can I take the values '@TaxableIncome' and '@BasePay' from an existing table instead?

Comment: @Ralph yes you can. But think about the work you are going to do, after that choose your tool. It seems that you can do this calculations without anything, just by using a simple SELECT query

Comment: Yes definitely but I have a requirement to do it as stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t understand how you planned to write, but I’ll give my version:

1. You can create a temporary table and write the results into it.
2. You can simply declare several variables and display them at the end of your decisions.

Code:

```
Declare @a decimal(6,2),
        @b decimal(6,2),
        @c decimal(6,2)

SET @A = @TotalHrsWorked * @HourlyRate
SET @B = @BasePay - @TaxableIncome
SET @C = @TaxableIncome/@BasePay

SELECT @A, @B, @C
```

RETURN is needed for functions that return values, and the procedure performs an action without returning any value.

Comment: Thank you @Mirzjali for your answer, but it was probably down-voted because answers are supposed to be in English.